# What to do when a question was linked to the incorrect duplicate?

Tags: discussion

https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/27642/6166 is closed as a duplicate, which is correct.

Yet it is closed against [Can you extend your own life with the death note?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13975/6166) , which it isn't a duplicate of. It is actually a duplicate of [Can I increase my lifespan by killing myself using the Death Note?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/907/6166)

All questions seem the same, but the second question is a little bit different. I edited its title to clarify the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raise a flag with a custom reason and myself or one of the mods will fix it - I've done it for you now.

Something like 'question should be closed as duplicate of *question* instead because *optional reasons* should give us the idea quickly and get a quick turnaround on it